# Managing MySQL SET datatype in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, types, set

I have a column `'Ambience'` of the following datatype in a `MySQL` database:

```
set('Funny', 'Sad', 'Scary')
```

I am querying the data through PHP with:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Films");
```

I am wondering how to deal with this data type on the client-side. For example, I want to find a film that is scary and print it. Should I treat the whole SET datatype as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is bad design as you need to search for specific values of `Ambience` filed. You can use `FIND_IN_SET`, but your query will be slow. Turn to atomic values for `Ambience`

Comment: So what do you think would be the best way to store multiple values for 'Ambience'? Is it a good idea to create a separate table just for Ambience (e.g using boolean (BIT?) dataype for each column? There woudl be 3 columns: 'Funny', 'Sad', 'Scary')

Comment: you can create new table with three colum and use table primary key to Ambience field that increase you performance (primary key should be integer )

Comment: Thanks @Saurabh Chandra Patel! Would still be an optimal solution if I had like 100 columns? (100 types of 'Ambience')

Comment: Well U didnt answer my last question :P. But thanks for the idea anyway.

Comment: Would you please explain slow, compared to what? how slow? is there any data to back it up?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a film that is scary:

```
SELECT * FROM Films WHERE FIND_IN_SET('Scary', Ambience) > 0;
```

Comment: That would be slow as Saurabh Chandra Patel noticed.